# How to set error message when form submited (Elementor Pro hook)

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

from elementorPro hook example.

I'm no idea.

How to use $handler for set error meassage when form is submited.

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {
    //make sure its our form
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

    // Replace MY_FORM_NAME with the name you gave your form
    if ( 'MY_FORM_NAME' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }

    if(someting error){
        $handler->..............  /* how to set error message .*/
     }


}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`$handler->add_error_message( "YOUR MESSAGE HERE" );`

This will add a custom message in addition to your default message. However you can also customize the default message on the Elementor Pro form builder interface. The Elementor Pro file ajax_handler.php will have the full set of public functions available.